# With the way that AI works, could a game predict the exact results before they happen, assuming there is no human interaction?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I've always wondered this about racing games, although the same goes for shooters. In the case of racing, when you finish a race, it either calculates the results on the spot and ends, or the AI keeps racing and it gives them a score as they finish.

Could games like this potentially calculate the results as soon as the human player has no control over the game, but then simulate all the AI normally to get the same results, without any influence from the calculated results? I'm guessing the AI only uses a very small amount of processing compared to what's required to render the scene, but I've never looked into it so I'm not really sure.

Personally I think it'd be quite cool to see in a game, or perhaps even having a hidden option (only accessible through a console command) for realtime feedback of whose going to win, where you can see how devastating your crashes/killing sprees are for the other players final score. I know something like that wouldn't be easy, I'm just surprised I've never seen it done yet.

Comment: Never played Mario Kart 64? Don't know if they spoofed the times or actually computed the whole end of the race, but they include race times without actually doing visuals for the end of the race.

Comment: 100% depends on the game's engine and console limitations